# Azure API Managment Analytics Geography always "Other" instead of real location

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

We have Azure API Management in internal VNet mode and make it publicly available by placing an Application Gateway in front of it. Everything works fine, but I noticed that in the API Management Analytics section, under Geography, I only see aggregation by "Other" instead of by country.
One one line is shown.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The IP to Geography mapping that APIM uses is based on a static internal DB that may not provide 100% correct info. There is no ETA or guarantees that it will provide 100% accurate information about the user's geography. You're welcome to log client IP in Log Analytics and use any 3rd party service that may provide better information please let me know incase of further queries I would be glad to assist you.